# Writing content from a file to another file on set time intervals using delimiters

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I'm trying to write a script in bash that reads a file `file1` and writes to another file `file2` every 2 seconds, which is easy enough.

However, I want to write to `file2` on either a line by line basis or using delimiters.

For example:

```
File1 = Some text goes in here
```

I want to write to `file2` every 2 seconds the first word `Some`, but only once, after 2 seconds the second word and so on until the end of `file1`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd convert the delimiter to new lines to achieve "line by line basis *or* delimiters", something like:

Script:

```
echo -e "foo:bar\nbaz" > myfile
i=0
while read -r foo; do 
    echo $i $foo
    i=$((i += 1))
done < <(cat myfile | tr ':' '\n')
```

Output:

```
0 foo
1 bar
2 baz
```

Answer (score 1):

One python script example from where you can start to write the script you want, reading the words from the first file and printing to stdout, but you can open another file and write there

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time

File = open("words", "r")
Wordlist = File.readline().split()

n = 0

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    print "File2 = " + Wordlist[n] #you can change this
    n = n + 1
    if n == Wordlist.__len__():
            break
```

Comment: Yeah, ok +1 for you on this. I was so caught up in doing it in bash I forgot there are easier ways. Thank you.